# Converting data from 8 bits to 12 bits

Tags: algorithm

I am getting signal that is stored as a buffer of char data (8 bits).
I am also getting the same signal plus 24 dB and my boss told me that it should be possible to reconstruct from those two buffers, one (which will be used as output) that will be stored as 12 bits.
I would like to know the mathematical operation that can do that and why choosing +24dB.
Thanks (I am dumb ><).

Comment: You need a lot more context before that can be answered.  What would sample data look like now?  What is it supposed to look like when you're finished?  What sort of system is the data stored in?  What sort of mechanism are you planning to employ to perform this conversion?

Comment: What format is the second buffer?

Comment: +24dB is equivalent to multiplying by 16.  However, it's not clear why receiving the same signal twice is helpful.  I'm not sure there's a definitive answer to this with the information you've given/

Comment: So, let me get this straight.. you have an 8 bit value that represents the signal, and then you have some amplitude that is represented as 24db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the problem statement, I guess you have an analog signal which are sampled at two amlitudes. Both signals has a resolution of 8 bits, but one is shifted and truncated.

You could get a 12 bit signal by combining the upper 4 bits of the first signal, and concatenating them with the second signal.

```c
sOut = ((sIn1 & 0xF0) << 4) | sIn2
```

---

If you want to get a little better accuracy, you could try to calculate an average over the common bits of the two signals. Normally, the lower 4 bits of the first signal should be approximately equal to the upper 4 bits of the second signal. Due to rounding-errors or noise, the values could be slightly different. One of the values could even have overflowed, and moved to the other end of the range.

```c
int Combine(byte sIn1, byte sIn2)
{
    int a = sIn1 >> 4; // Upper 4 bits
    int b1 = sIn1 & 0x0F; // Common middle 4 bits
    int b2 = sIn2 >> 4;  // Common middle 4 bits
    int c = sIn2 & 0x0F; // Lower 4 bits

    int b;

    if (b1 >= 12 && b2 < 4)
    {
        // Assume b2 has overflowed, and wrapped around to a smaller value.
        // We need to add 16 to it to compensate the average.
        b = (b1 + b2 + 16)/2;
    }
    else if (b1 < 4 && b2 >= 12)
    {
        // Assume b2 has underflowed, and wrapped around to a larger value.
        // We need to subtract 16 from it to compensate the average.
        b = (b1 + b2 - 16)/2;
    }
    else
    {
        // Neither or both has overflowed. Just take the average.
        b = (b1 + b2)/2;
    }

    // Construct the combined signal.
    return a * 256 + b * 16 + c;
}
```

When I tested this, it reproduced the signal accurately more often than the first formula.

Comment: I will try to give more information, but first thanks a lot for all the replies. I have a signal that is coming twice. First at 0dB then a second time with a 24dB gain. The signal is the same except for the noise (it is an analog signal). This signal is provided as samples of 8bits data. I am trying to use those two signals to make one output buffer storing those data as 12bits sampled data, and I am looking for the math behind this operation.

Comment: Jeremy : The sample data are from an analog source and I am receiving them in my software. So the operation 8bits -> 12 bits has to be done in software. I can't tell you what they are supposed to look like after processing since they can have different "shape".

Comment: Oli : "However, it's not clear why receiving the same signal twice is helpful" -> The purpose of the second signal with +24dB gain would be to have data for the conversion from 8bits to 12 bits.

Comment: Markus : This is a clear solution, but I am not smart at all and I don't understand the binary operation. Why only the 4 LSB bits of the first signal ?

Comment: @Toyo See my updated answer. I wasn't quite happy with just throwing the lower four bits of the first signal. Now I take the average of the common bits.

Comment: @Toyo: I understand that.  But either the +24dB signal will clip/overflow, or the 0dB signal will undergo truncation rounding.  You will need to specify the clipping/overflow/truncation/rounding behaviour of your data acquisition in order to answer the question.